# Post method in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

I need some help on with a post method.

Here is a post method I use for some card payment using stripe

```
app.post('/charge', (req, res) => {
  const amount = 2500;
  stripe.customers
    .create({
      email: req.body.stripeEmail,
      source: req.body.stripeToken,
    })
    .then((customer) =>
      stripe.charges.create({
        amount,
        description: 'Web Development eBook',
        currency: 'usd',
        customer: customer.id,
      })
    )
    .then((charge) => res.render('success'));
});
```

in the same method I want to add the following method which works for now only with postman

```
exports.addTransaction = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { text, amount } = req.body;

    const transaction = await Transactions.create(req.body);

    return res.status(201).json({
      success: true,
      data: transaction,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json({
      success: false,
      error: 'Server Error! Transaction was not added',
    });
  }
};
```

and the body that I want to send through the POST method is smth like this

```
{
    "text": "Book",
    "amount": -23
}
```

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/https.html

Comment: What error you get???

Comment: I don't get any errors. It is working fine, but in order to get the body with text and amount into my database I used postman to do that. Now I want to implement that method in the same post method as the first one. When the transaction with stripe card is done, I want some Info to be created in my database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are confused by the async/await example. The async/await syntax works on the promise, just like the `then` function, the `await` waits for the function execution and returns the data to the variable which awaits the same.

Consider the following examples to check the difference between async/await and the promise syntax

```
function myPromise() {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve(5);
   });
}
```

Now, we can call the above function with two different syntax

```
myPromise.then((data) => {
  console.log(data); // prints 5
});
```

Or, we can use modern `async/await` like this,

```
const data = await myPromise();
```

The above function will only work if the function in which it is wrapped has `async` in the beginning.

for example:

```
async function getData() {
  const data = await myPromise();
  console.log(data);
}
```

Notice the `async` keyword before the `function` keyword, without the `async` keyword the function would not work.

Also, just like `catch` in the regular promise, we use `try/catch` to catch the errors.

Now, coming back to your problem, you could convert the second function to use `then().catch()` order or you could convert your first function to use `async/await` style. Or you can use the combination of both.

Below, I've implemented the `then/catch` version of your second function inside your first function

```
app.post('/charge', (req, res) => {
  const { text, amount } = req.body;
  stripe.customers
    .create({
      email: req.body.stripeEmail,
      source: req.body.stripeToken,
    })
    .then((customer) =>
      stripe.charges.create({
      amount,
      description: 'Web Development eBook',
      currency: 'usd',
      customer: customer.id,
  });
)
.then((charge) => {
    Transactions.create(req.body).then(() => {
       res.status(201).json({
       success: true,
       data: transaction,
      });
    }).catch((e) => {
       res.status(500).json({
       success: false,
       error: 'Server Error! Transaction was not added',
      });
    });
});
```

});

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer. I have made the changes you suggested but now I get this error when trying the POST method:

Comment: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:470:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\SerbanBondor\Desktop\Book_Seller\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\SerbanBondor\Desktop\Book_Seller\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\SerbanBondor\Desktop\Book_Seller\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)

Comment: (node:9052) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:9052) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:9052) [DEP0018]

Comment: Hi,
The first error comes when you send the response twice with the same `res` object, in your case your `res.status` statements are being called twice. 

The second error simply suggests the there is a promise in your code that doesn't have a catch block associated with it. The promises that don't have catch blocks displays `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` when an error is thrown.

Comment: Funny thing is it works, even though I get the error message

Comment: Ok. I understand what you are saying. Why does it send the response twice?

Comment: Yes, it will work, it sends the response to the client, and then the error occurs, your code then tried to send the error in response, but the response is already sent, hence the error. you should handle the error and log the same to look for possible causes of the error.

Comment: Not yet. Still trying to. Here is my final piece of code: https://ibb.co/2Ysxzw0   How can I improve this piece of code?

Comment: res.render and res.status both cannot be used at once as both of them will try to send the response and the latter on will fail

Comment: Also, incorrect placement of then function, customer.create.then.then should be replaced by customer.create.then(customer.charges.then) instead.

Comment: Yes. I have been able to make it work partially. I placed the function correctly and removed the res.render from the method and I have no error now, but I don't really know where to place res.render now in order to make it redirect to the other page after the payment is done

Comment: you can either call res.json or res.render, both cannot be called at once, please share your latest code if you are still stuck. If you found my answer helpful please go ahead and press the upvote button, also you can accept the answer as well

Comment: Yes you are right. there can only be one res.json or res.render, but the how can I redirect to the success page in the same post method? or should I do it different?

Comment: Use if statements, if it is success call res.render else call res.json or whatever you want